# Mobile Safari, Css animations freeze on navigation

Tags: css, animation, mobile, safari, css-animations

So I'm working on a mobile website for a client and have added a css loading animation that triggers when users navigate pages or on ajax load.

The animations work fine in Chrome, but in IOS I've found that immediately after triggering navigation (via window.location.href or just clicking an anchor tag), the loading animation just freezes. This happens at the beginning of the call, not after the page is loaded, so there is a decent amount of time where the css isn't doing anything and the site looks like its hung up on something. I'd also add that the animation works when I'm just doing ajax calls.

In the meantime I've set up a delay between when the animation loads and when the navigation actually happens, and it helps somewhat with the look and feel of the site, but its not great.

Any solutions or ideas around why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Animations freezing after navigation is triggered seems to be a general issue with Webkit browsers.

See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16177

There is a workaround if you can send the request via Ajax/XHR. Then the animation will keep playing. You can trigger the navigation after receiving a 200/ok response from the backend service.

Should you load the entire next page and swap content by Javascript, you may want to pay attention to the browser history API, i.e. add an entry to it for the swapped page.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a workaround if that suits your case: using `transform` instead of all other properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178319/647845